# Excel+vba+Oracle Too slow connections, maybe something wrong in my code

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

We work with excel daily and we also use company apps. Oracle is for database.
I want to obtain data from oracle database directly to avoid get from company apps but it's too slow to be useful.

At this moment this is what I have:
First I select an excel cell, there is the client_id.
Then launch vba code. Make 3 queries, just need to solve how many 'x', quantities, not data.
Finally write down the result in different cells.

This is my code:

```
Sub ConnectToOracle(my_query As String)

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mtxData As Variant

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open ("User ID=**my_obdc**;Password=**mypassword**; Data Source=**mydatasource**; Provider=oraOLEDB.Oracle")

rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
rs.Open (my_query), cn

mtxData = rs.GetRows

Worksheets(1).Activate

'write down query results in selected excel cell names 
Select Case my_column
    Case 1
    ActiveSheet.Range("Query1_cell") = mtxData
    Case 2
    ActiveSheet.Range("Query2_cell") = mtxData
    Case 3
    ActiveSheet.Range("Query3_cell") = mtxData
    
End Select

'cleanup in the end
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub



Sub ConnectTest()

Dim client_id
client_id = ActiveCell.Value 'get client id from excel cell

Call ConnectToOracle("SELECT Count(*) FROM TABLE_1 " & _
                     "WHERE (TABLE_1.CALL_YEAR='2023') AND (TABLE_1.client_id=" & call_seq & ") AND (TABLE_1.ACTUAL_TIME Is Null)")
Call ConnectToOracle("SELECT Count(*) FROM TABLE_2 " & _
                     "WHERE (TABLE_2.CALL_YEAR='2023') AND (TABLE_2.client_id=" & call_seq & ") AND (TABLE_2.city='NY')")
Call ConnectToOracle("SELECT Count(*) FROM TABLE_2 " & _
                     "WHERE (TABLE_2.CALL_YEAR='2023') AND (TABLE_2.client_id=" & call_seq & ") AND (TABLE_2.country='USA')")

End Sub
```

This is working well, queries are done and results are writing down. But it's too slow. Around 7-8 seconds in total. That means I can't use this to get lot of data.

But take note that if I make a connection and then if I use old Microsoft Query, I can make manually any of these queries very fast. So I think my code is not the best one.

Comment: Perhaps the Codereview Stack?

Comment: You're connecting to oracle for every call. do a connect first, then use that open connection for all three calls, afterwards close the connection

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was doing extra connections. I just follow below comment to do connection only once, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the connection once, use it for multiple queries, the close the connection.

Something like:

*(Note: this is untested but it should give you an idea of the methodology even if you have to fix the syntax.)*

```vba
Private Function ConnectToOracle()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open ("User ID=**my_obdc**;Password=**mypassword**; Data Source=**mydatasource**; Provider=oraOLEDB.Oracle")
    ConnectToOracle = cn
End Function

Private Sub ExecuteQuery( _
    cn As ADODB.Connection, _
    my_query AS String, _
    mtxData As Range _
)
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    rs.Open (my_query), cn

    mtxData = rs.GetRows

    rs.close()
    'cleanup in the end
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ConnectTest()
    Dim client_id
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    client_id = ActiveCell.Value 'get client id from excel cell

    Worksheets(1).Activate

    Set cn = ConnectToOracle()

    Call ExecuteQuery( _
        cn, _
        "SELECT Count(*) FROM TABLE_1" _
        & " WHERE call_year = '2023'"
        & " AND   client_id = " & call_seq _
        & " AND   actual_time IS NULL", _
        ActiveSheet.Range("Query1_cell") _
    )

    Call ExecuteQuery( _
        cn, _
        "SELECT Count(*) FROM TABLE_2" _
        & " WHERE call_year = '2023'"
        & " AND   client_id = " & call_seq _
        & " AND   city      = 'NY'", _
        ActiveSheet.Range("Query2_cell") _
    )

    Call ExecuteQuery( _
        cn, _
        "SELECT Count(*) FROM TABLE_3" _
        & " WHERE call_year = '2023'"
        & " AND   client_id = " & call_seq _
        & " AND   country   = 'USA'", _
        ActiveSheet.Range("Query3_cell") _
    )

    cn.close()
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```